# Short film: Home robbery with reversed gender roles

Tags: story-identification, short-film, feminism

I'm trying to find a short film again that I watched a while ago, probably on YouTube. The setting is in a society that has entirely reversed gender roles, but is otherwise very similar to ours.

The plot is about a family that could probably be characterized as white trash living in a suburban house. The family is led by a matriarch, a tough, non-nonsense woman in her 40s. She has adult daughters living at home. One of them is a car aficionado and, I think, owns a spiffed-up ride.

The family is assaulted and robbed by a gang led by another, younger woman who pretended to be the new neighbor, so that she was invited inside.

There are maybe two men in the household. The movie entirely reverses the gender roles: The men perform the stereotypical female household roles and wear aprons. The women tell them what to do. At some point during the robbery the matriarch makes a stand, saying something along the lines "I can tolerate [all kinds of abuse] but I cannot let you beat [or scare, frighten, harass, assault?] my men", again gender-reversing a stereotypically protective male attitude towards women. At some point she takes a pretty heavy beating herself in a very stoic fashion.

All my attempts to find this movie again failed, partly because the keywords to search for are all very common.

Comment: Can you recall any additional details that would make this fall into either the Science Fiction or Fantasy categories?

Comment: What exactly is "white trash" though? Just trying to understand the context.

Comment: @Xantec Well, the entire world (what we see of it) seems gender-reversed, so I think it falls into the category of an alternate reality fantasy.

Comment: @Clockwork Poor, not well educated, simple housing (although they own a modest house that is one step up from a trailer, I think). Perhaps alcohol or drug problems.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica It definitely falls under the fiction genre, but nothing about the setting as described sets it as science- or fantasy- fiction, IMO. If you took something like *Memoirs of a Geisha* and simply swapped the genders would you consider that sufficient to make it fantasy genre?

Comment: @Xantec Maybe you are right. I think I watched it when I was exploring short genre fiction, so in my mind it was in the category. But from a neutral perspective it may not be genre. I'm still not sure. It was striking enough to be more than an arbitrary family with reversed roles, and also the burglars were led by a woman. But I can delete it if it doesn't fit.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Eh, this is just my opinion so don't delete it. I've [posted on meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13762/1234) to see if this question fits what is on topic or not.

Comment: The presence of a professional "Women's Football Alliance" (e.g. clearly parodying the NFL) pushes this one firmly into 'alternate history' territory as far as in concerned.

Comment: @Valorum Well, the [WFA](https://wfaprofootball.com/) is an existing organization, as are the [West Michigan Mayhem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Michigan_Mayhem) on the poster. (But the player depicted may be fictional if she is Lori Jean Wilson). I *guess* such households could conceivably exist on this side of the mirror as well ;-).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica - I do stand humbly corrected. I was thrown for a loop by how poorly made the poster was and assumed it was put together by the filmmakers :-) That being said, the maker's website indicates that game on screen is from the IWFL which appears to have replaced the NFL in this reality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short is **Hail Mary Country** by **Tannaz Hazemi**<sup>1</sup>, and it didn't disappoint when I revisited it, quite to the contrary: It is very well made. I recommend watching it, [there is a copy on vimeo](https://vimeo.com/286448015). Lori Jean Wilson impresses in the role of the matriarch.

Whether it can be considered fantasy genre, in the sense of an alternate reality, is probably still unclear. While the gender reversal appears not restricted to the specific household where the robbery takes place, there is little to no depiction of other parts of the society. There *is* a poster of the [Women's Football Alliance](https://wfaprofootball.com/) and the women's team [West Michigan Mayhem](https://www.instagram.com/westmichiganmayhem), both of which exist in our reality.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I found the movie by skimming through two years (the age of the laptop on which I correctly thought I watched it) of YouTube browser history in a bout of desperation. I was lucky enough to not scroll past it, helped by the fact that I appear to watch shorts in clusters. The YouTube copy itself was removed, which is probably why my previous keyword searches had come up empty.</sub>

Comment: Don't forget to self-accept, of course.